# Convert LINQ stored procedure to SQL inline query

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures, converters

I'm new to LINQ and I would like to convert code execution of stored procedure (executed in **C#/LINQ**) into SQL code. I want to execude those in SSMS.

```
try 
{
    using(var context = new Cubicle_EntityEntities()) 
    {
        lst = context.usp_searchUserProject(project.ProjectType,
                                            project.ProjectStage,
                                            Convert.ToInt32(project.ProjectCode),
                                            project.ClientProjectNo,
                                            project.ClientAssetID, 
                                            Convert.ToInt32(project.ProjectStatus), 
                                            project.ProjectStartDate,
                                            project.ProjectEndDate,
                                            project.ProjectLeader,
                                            UserID,
                                            ProjectStatusArchived)
                      .ToList<usp_searchUserProject_Result>();

        list = lst.Where(a => a.ProjectStatus == Convert.ToString(ProjectStatusClosed))
                  .ToList<usp_searchUserProject_Result>();

    }
}
```

Comment: there are two part: context.usp_searchUserProject have no idea about this, for lst.where, I think it's quit simple, I think you are ask for context.usp_searchUserProject part.

Comment: usp_searchUserProject is a stored procedure name available in sql database. and Cubicle_EntityEntities() is just get, set methods...and lst is object of list

Comment: so basically you want to convert `usp_searchUserProject` to `linq` query?

Comment: No..the above is linq lamba expressions applying on stored procedure 'usp_searchUserProject '...so I want to convert this in sql inline query...so I can check this on my SSMS

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put the essence of the `where` in the actual stored proc?  Kinda defeats the purpose of SPs and now your business logic is in two places

Comment: @MickyD..Yes business logic is in two placess...So can we convert it in inline query?

Comment: Well inline queries are even worse. 1) There is no compile-time checking 2) business logic is scattered through the codebase 3) are a security risk

Comment: Ohh ok..thank you..but I need to convert it to just check on my SSMS...

Comment: If you just want to check it, run your linq on LinqPad. That will give you the output

Comment: If we all understood your question correctly, that means the only thing you want is to **execute stored procedure** directly in SSMS, is it correct?

Comment: Yes...and it is in linq...and I'm unable to do it...Not able to convert in sql inline query

Comment: @Tatranskymedved execute Store Procedure in SSMS? actually im a bit confuse about this question...

Answer (score 0):

Add brake point and then when debugger stop at brake point clear output window.
hit f10 and get your SQL code.